# how can i get the interval in hrs AM to PM and PM to AM

Tags: c#

i need help guys im creating an Overtime computation and when im trying to get the value of the value hrs it became negative when i subtract the PM to AM and PM to PM coz i need to count the hrs when it reach at 10:00 PM heres my code

```
         string value = comboBox91.Text;
         string value2 = comboBox92.Text;
         string awtsu = value;
         DateTime dt;
         DateTime dt2;

         dt = DateTime.Parse(value);
         string mystring;
         mystring = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt");

         dt2 = DateTime.Parse(value2);
         string mystring2;
         mystring2 = dt2.ToString("hh:mm tt");


         double diff2 = (dt2 - dt).TotalHours;
         textBox8.Text = Convert.ToString(diff2) + "Hrs";

         string pmm = "10:00 PM";

         DateTime pm = DateTime.Parse(pmm);
         string mystring3;
         mystring3 = pm.ToString("hh:mm tt");




         if (dt2 > pm)
         {
             double diff = (dt - dt2).TotalHours;
             textBox9.Text = Convert.ToString(diff) + "Hrs";


         }
         else
         {
             textBox9.Text = ("0");
         }
```

$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I understand your requirements:

1. A worker starts at a standard time (8:30 AM) and usually finish at a standard time (6:30 PM), but may work later.  In theory that person might work past midnight into the next day.
2. If they work past 7 PM up to 10 PM they get paid one overtime rate.
3. If they work past 10 those hours are paid a second rate.

So, the first thing you would declare in your code is a list of these overtime boundaries:

```
    public static readonly TimeSpan[] OvertimeBoundaries = 
    {
        TimeSpan.FromHours(19), // 7 PM
        TimeSpan.FromHours(22)  // 10 PM.
    };
```

[TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a structure that represents an interval of time and is appropriate to represent a daily event.

Next, given a workers start and end times, you want to measure the total number of hours for each of these intervals:

```
    public static TimeSpan[] GetOvertimeWorked(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, IList<TimeSpan> overtimeBoundaries)
    {
        var overtimeWorked = new TimeSpan[overtimeBoundaries.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < overtimeBoundaries.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var time1 = startDateTime.Date + overtimeBoundaries[i];
            var time2 = startDateTime.Date + overtimeBoundaries[i + 1];
            if (time1 > time2)
                throw new ArgumentException("overtimeBoundaries are not in order");
            if (endDateTime > time2)
                overtimeWorked[i] = time2 - time1;
            else if (endDateTime > time1)
                overtimeWorked[i] = endDateTime - time1;
            else
                overtimeWorked[i] = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        if (overtimeWorked.Length > 0)
        {
            var timeLast = startDateTime.Date + overtimeBoundaries[overtimeBoundaries.Count - 1];
            if (endDateTime > timeLast)
                overtimeWorked[overtimeBoundaries.Count - 1] = endDateTime - timeLast;
            else
                overtimeWorked[overtimeBoundaries.Count - 1] = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        return overtimeWorked;
    }
```

Finally you need to extract the appropriate date & time information from your user interface, call the above utility to get overtime hours worked, and display it.

Your code would be much more comprehensible if you named your variables meaningfully rather than with names like "dt2" and "awtsu".  You should also, at the minimum, separate your business logic from the code that loads and unloads data from the user interface.

Finally, I will note that the following is dangerous:

```
    string pmm = "10:00 PM";
    DateTime pm = DateTime.Parse(pmm);
```

The problem here is that, if you pass "DateTime.Parse" a string with only a "time of day" component, it will [fill in the date information with the current clock setting on your computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#StringToParse).  This would likely produce random, hard to reproduce bugs if you put your application into production, because the app might or might not be run on a different day than the workers worked!

Comment: umm in my case all employee starts at 8:30am and finish at 6:30pm after that the overtime start at 7pm and when it reach at 10 pm another count of hour. becoz after 10 pm the salary of overtime increases . meaning 7-10pm and 10pm onwards are different salary. help me guys thx

Comment: So you need the number of hours worked between 7 and 10, and also the number of hours worked after 10?

Comment: yes sir exactly.. and when im about to get the hours in 7pm between 2am the value are incorrect